# Re-triggering an AWS Lambda function which reads from a Kafka queue

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, aws-lambda

I have written an AWS lambda function, which starts every 15 minutes. The function reads from a Kafka queue for 2 minutes, stores them in a temporary file, and at the end of 2 minutes, if uploads the file to an S3 bucket.

Presently, the bucket does not have the lambda's IAM role in its write policy, so upload to S3 is throwing an exception. All of this is fine, and once the appropriate policies are added, there should not be exceptions.

I have some doubts with reference to the above:

1. The lambda function keeps coming up after every 2 minutes. Is this because the previous invocation ended with an error?
2. Since I'm reading from the Kafka, I'm using a fixed group id so that I do not read messages twice. Suppose the lambda fails midway due to some issue (not the connectivity issue, but something else). If another function comes up, it will start reading from the last read message. However, since the previous invocation failed midway and could not write the messages to the S3 bucket, the second invocation will miss those messages. Is there a way I don't miss those messages? ( I have an idea to store offsets in S3 after every invocation is completed, and assign these offsets manually to the consumer, so that if any invocation fails midway, the offsets won't be affected and I won't lose any messages. But if there's a way to avoid reading from S3, that would be great).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around and playing with the lambda, I finally got the answers:

1. Yes, `lambda function` is re-triggered for a couple of times if the previous invocation ends with an error. This can be configured in the `lambda` properties.
2. Writing to the `S3` bucket was the ultimate step. Since I wanted to ensure that offsets were not updated for the next invocation, the idea was to set `auto-commit` feature in `consumer-configurations` to `false`. Then manually commit after the write to S3 bucket was complete. This would ensure that the next invocation of lambda would start reading from the beginning if write to S3 failed.